# Data Loader Issue in salesforce

Tags: data-loader

I have created the field set as External Id and now I am changing the field to set as unique record identifier, I am not able to change, because Records exist already with duplicate values for that field.

So I want to query all the duplicate records. How do I perform a query to display the duplicate values for that particular field in test sandbox?

I am using Dataloader for the issue,i am having 1 crore records,whether the Group by Query will work in dataloader ,after extracting all the Records what is the formula to seperate all the Duplicate Values,What is the Solution ,How to perform these issues in Data Loader,Anyone Guide Me For the Answer

I am Having the Data Loader Version 32.0

Comment: You can export all the records using a data loader. Then, you can use "Remove duplicates" function of excel to remove all the duplicates from extracted data.

Comment: After Removing Duplicates,we can Upload the Data to test Sandbox@Devendra

Comment: @I want seperate Duplicates Record into another file How?

Comment: @Anyone Please Guide me for the issue

Comment: What do you want to do with the duplicates? Remove one of them (randomly?) or clear one of the duplicate fields?

Comment: (1) get records into Excel worksheet 1 -- including ID field, (2) make copy of worksheet 1 into worksheet 1, (3) excel remove duplicates from worksheet 2, (4) Use vlookup in worksheet 1 to see if row present in worksheet 2 (match on ID column ). rows with value `#N/A` are the duplicates and savable into a separate file using save as